# Creating A Relationship Between Two User Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

Im building a website which will have teachers and students. Im using the default Django User models and originally ignored Teachers and treated all my Users as Students. Today I began trying to separate my users into Teachers and Students and am having a lot of difficulty. Im obviously missing some fundamental knowledge and have read a lot online but am going around in circles.

A teacher can have many students and a student can have one teacher.

First I thought Id need separate Student and Teacher models. So everyone now is a User, and I will attach either a Student or Teacher model to each (is this sloppy?).

Now for the relationship. I tried creating a relationship between teachers and students within their own models, but it didnt work so I figured id need a separate TeacherStudentRelationship class to hold the relationships.

This is my implementation so far:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.student.username}'

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.teacher.username}'

class TeacherStudentRelationship(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This doesnt throw any errors, though in Django Admin I can create multiple instances of TeacherStudentRelationship and assign a student to a teacher in multiple instances (should only be able to assign a student to a teacher once). I can also only assign a single student to a single teacher within one instance even though the relationship is one-to-many.

I also have a problem with my implementation. I have a signal fire every time a user is created which generates a Student model and links it with the User. This is fine when I have students enrolling on my site, though it means my Admin also needs a Student model (or else it throws errors). I also planned on creating Teachers in the Django Admin panel, but this will cause issues there too as they will need Student models. How would you implement this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a separate relationship like this, you can have a [**`ManyToMany`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) Relation in your teacher model. Like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.student.username}'

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

In that way, it won't need to create new student when you are create a Teacher instance or vice versa.

### Update

From comments, unfortunately you can't remove signals unless you use [custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) in django. You can try like this:

```
CHOICES = (('student', "Student"), ('teacher', "Teacher"))

class User(AbstractUser):
   user_type = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=255)
   has_teacher = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, default=None)

   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_type', 'email']
```

Then, you can define what kind of user it is during the User creating process, hence you do not need the signals. Also, you can store auth data of student and teacher in same model.

Comment: Hi, OP said that "A teacher can have many students and a student can have one teacher". That's Many to One, rather than M2M.

Comment: Thank you. I thought ManyToMany would be no good as a student can only have one teacher, I will read up on it. And I understand what you mean by not having to create a student when I create a teacher and vice versa. If you dont mind, could you please point me in the right direction of how to create a Student when a user enrols with Django's inbuilt user registration, rather than it creating a User by default (and therefore I can remove my signal which creates the Student)?

Comment: @Brenden please see the update section of the answer

Comment: Thank you very much. This has given me something I can work on. I will try adding an IF statement in signals to check if the User is a student and if so, create the extra models. Thanks :)